# Nginx reverse proxy arbitrary directory to subdomain

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, dynamic-dns

We currently use Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of several IOT devices to access them from outside our internal network.  Up until now, I've statically mapped a location to each device's interal IP address.

We're adding several devices that use dynamic DNS in for form of `http://DeviceName.ServiceName.com` but we want them to appear in the form of `https://OurDomain.com/DeviceName/` in our current directory structure along side the other devices.  There are going to be lots of these new devices, and I'd rather make a dynamic rule that will take the DeviceName from the URL and send the request to the correct device.

How do I set a variable from the URL and re-write it in my proxy_pass so I don't end sending the request to `http://DeviceName.ServiceName.com/DeviceName/`

I'm trying to follow the format at https://chrismarslender.com/2014/07/21/url-based-variables-nginx/ and I've tried:

```
server {
listen 80;
    server_name OurDomain.com./(?P<DeviceName>)$;
    root /var/www/html/

    location / {
    proxy_pass http://$DeviceName.ServiceName.com;
}
```

I've left the HTTPS stuff out of the code I posted, but haven't had trouble proxying our internal HTTP devices on our existing HTTPS site through Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/html/;

    location ~ ^/(?:[^/]+)/(?P<path>.+)$ {
        proxy_pass http://$DeviceName.example.net/$path;
    }
}
```

I replaced `ourdomain.com` with `example.com` and `ServiceName.com` with `example.net`.

I changed the `server_name` from your version, since you have only one domain in use for the proxy virtual server.

In the `location` block, the regular expression picks up the first part of the normalized URI and then picks up the rest of the URI and stores it into the `$path` variable. That is then used in the `proxy_pass` destination.

You might need to tweak the `location` regular expression, if you have URLs like `http://example.com/device`, that is without the last slash character.